# JavaScript animation scroll up and down

Tags: javascript, animation, button

How do you make JavaScript animation scroll both to the bottom of an element and back to the top? I am still learning about JavaScript and found an example code from w3schools, which, when I modified it to scroll back to the top, worked in the Tryit Editor, using the exact same code for the myUP function I have below. Though I know that in its current state, combined with the other function, this same code is not currently working.

I have a hunch that there was something not good about the code, even when it worked fine by itself in the Tryit Editor. I feel that in the future it would not work properly. Am I right to assume this, and, if so, what should I be doing to achieve this in JavaScript instead?

```html
<html>
<style>
#myContainer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
}
#tester {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: gray;
}
</style>
<body>

<p>
<button onmousedown="myMove()">DOWN</button> 
</p>
<p>
<button onmousedown="myUP()">UP</button> 
</p>

<div id ="myContainer">
<div id ="tester"></div>
</div>

<script>
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("tester");   
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 20);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 500) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++; 
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
     
    }
  }
}

function myUP() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("tester");   
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 20);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 500) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++; 
      elem.style.bottom = pos + 'px'; 
       
    }
  }
}

   

  
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: w3schools.. lol.. some good and professional advice: avoid that site. if you need references for anything use mdn instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the working code now,

Your code were making problem in `UP` function.

```
function myUP() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("tester");   
  var pos = 500;// Changed the max position.
  var id = setInterval(frame, 20);
  function frame() {
    console.log(pos);
    if (pos == 0) { //reverse condition to 0
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos--; // reverse the position
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; // that should be back to top

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<style>
#myContainer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
}
#tester {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: gray;
}
</style>
<body>

<p>
<button onmousedown="myMove()">DOWN</button> 
</p>
<p>
<button onmousedown="myUP()">UP</button> 
</p>


<div id ="myContainer">
<div id ="tester"></div>
</div>

<script>
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("tester");   
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 20);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 500) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++; 
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
     
    }
  }
}
function myUP() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("tester");   
  var pos = 500;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  function frame() {
    console.log(pos);
    if (pos == 0) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos--; 
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
       
    }
  }
}

   

  
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit.007. You give excellent notes to the side. That does fix the problem.  I had previously tried to make the elem.style.top into elem.style.bottom = pos - 'px', which obviously didn't work.  Why does the elem.style remain the same as the myMove function?

Comment: If you inspect the element then you will get the CSS property of that element is at TOP:500px, so we have to reduce that CSS until it gets back to the 0 position.

Comment: Okay. Thanks again.  Great answers. You've been a big help.